# creating SSH tunnels while using xlwings in python

Tags: python, ssh

Has anyone been able to connect to an SSH server using paramiko, etc. in xlwings?  I've tried numerous ssh packages, can connect to the server in ipython, terminal python, etc. but it hangs in xlwings.

Setup is a mac.  I've done more testing and when starting xlwings from python, SSH works.  When starting xlwings from excel with a VBA button, it hangs.

```
import xlwings
from xlwings import *
import paramiko 

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(ssh_server, username=ssh_user, password=passwd)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls')

lines = []
for line in stdout:
    lines.append(line)
Range("A1").value = lines # test to make sure SSH is connected
```

Comment: Could you describe your setup with a little more details please?

Comment: updated with more information.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks for reporting - I've opened an issue here: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/98